# Limiting the timeout period for Selenium FindElement()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeout

How can I limit/reduce the timeout period for `FindElement`? I am scraping a website. For a table which appears in thousands of pages, I can have either an element stating there is no information, or the table.
I search for one of theses elements and when missing, I search for the other. The problem is that when one of them does not exist, it takes a long time until the `FindElement` times out. Can this period be shortened? Can the timeout period be defined per element? All I found about waits are to prolong the timeout period...
I'm working in a .NET environment, if that helps.

Comment: You can use implicit wait set its value as and when required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delay in `FindElement` is caused by the Implicit Wait settings. You can set it temporary to different value

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)); // setting to 0 will check one time only when using FindElement

// look for the elements

driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(original settings));
```

Comment: Eventually, that is what I did and saved a lot of time :-)